# Como añadir diccionarios a una lista y como acudir a ellos

Tags: python

En el problema tengo que acudir a cada diccionario y calcular el total de sus puntos para ver si es válido o no. Si es válido tengo que agregarlo a una lista, con el nombre del pokemon que aparece en el diccionario de entrada, pero no sé como acudir a ello, ya que lo he corregido y demás y no consigo poder poner el nombre del pokemon solo aparece nombre, al intentar introducir el diccionario dentro de la lista utilizo el atributo append pero encuentro un error, gracias por la ayuda.

```py
def construir_equipo_pokemon(cantidad:int, lista_pkmn:list)->list:
    
    nombres_pkmn = []
    puntos = 0
    i = 0
    nombres_pkmn = {}
    for diccionario in lista_pkmn:
        nombre = diccionario["nombre"]
        while i <= cantidad:
            puntos = int(diccionario["ataque"]+diccionario["defensa"]+diccionario["ataque_especial"]+diccionario["defensa_especial"]+diccionario["velocidad"]+diccionario["vida"])
            
            i += 1
            if puntos >= 600:
                
                dict_pkmn = {"nombre": puntos}
               #ERROR Y NO SE COMO ACUDIR AL NOMBRE PARA QUE EL RESULTADO NO ME "NOMBRE"
               # lista_pkmn.append(dict_pkmn)--> no se porque no puedo utilizar el atributo append en diccionarios
               
                
                
    if len(nombres_pkmn)  == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return nombres_pkmn
```

He probado con este:

```
lista = [{'nombre': 'Rayquaza', 'vida': 120, 'ataque': 120, 'defensa': 120, 'ataque_especial': 120, 'defensa_especial': 120, 'velocidad': 120}, {'nombre': 'Arceus', 'vida': 120, 'ataque': 120, 'defensa': 120, 'ataque_especial': 120, 'defensa_especial': 120, 'velocidad': 120}, {'nombre': 'Solgaleo', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 200, 'defensa_especial': 100, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Charizard-X', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 50, 'defensa_especial': 50, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Greninja', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 100, 'defensa_especial': 100, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Swellow', 'vida': 60, 'ataque': 80, 'defensa': 50, 'ataque_especial': 70, 'defensa_especial': 60, 'velocidad': 150}, {'nombre': 'Pikachu', 'vida': 20, 'ataque': 20, 'defensa': 20, 'ataque_especial': 20, 'defensa_especial': 20, 'velocidad': 20}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo en diccionario no puedes usar append no tiene sentido ya que las claves tienen que ser unicas, ejemplo no puede haber más de un "Nombre" dentro de un diccionario puedes usar update si quieres añadir algún campo con datos o sobrescribir otro.
Segundo la variable nombres_pkmn primero la declaras como lista y después como diccionario ¿en qué quedamos?.
Te he hecho una demo de como quedaria lo que me imagino:

```
def construir_equipo_pokemon(cantidad:int, lista_pkmn:list)->list:

nombres_pkmn = []
puntos = 0
i = 0
#nombres_pkmn ={}#no tiene sentido
for diccionario in lista_pkmn:
   # nombre = diccionario["nombre"]#no se si tiene sentido
 while i <= cantidad: #tampoco tiene mucho sentido ya que te saldran repetidos el mismo para todos
        puntos = int(diccionario["ataque"]+diccionario["defensa"]+diccionario["ataque_especial"]+diccionario["defensa_especial"]+diccionario["velocidad"]+diccionario["vida"])
    
        i += 1
        if puntos >= 600:
        
            nombres_pkmn.append(diccionario)
            
         
       #ERROR Y NO SE COMO ACUDIR AL NOMBRE PARA QUE EL RESULTADO NO ME "NOMBRE"
       # lista_pkmn.append(dict_pkmn)--> no se porque no puedo utilizar el atributo append en diccionarios
       
        
        
 if len(nombres_pkmn)  == 0:
    return None
 else:
    return nombres_pkmn
lista = [{'nombre': 'Rayquaza', 'vida': 120, 'ataque': 120, 'defensa': 120, 'ataque_especial': 120, 'defensa_especial': 120, 'velocidad': 120}, {'nombre': 'Arceus', 'vida': 120, 'ataque': 120, 'defensa': 120, 'ataque_especial': 120, 'defensa_especial': 120, 'velocidad': 120}, {'nombre': 'Solgaleo', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 200, 'defensa_especial': 100, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Charizard-X', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 50, 'defensa_especial': 50, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Greninja', 'vida': 100, 'ataque': 100, 'defensa': 100, 'ataque_especial': 100, 'defensa_especial': 100, 'velocidad': 100}, {'nombre': 'Swellow', 'vida': 60, 'ataque': 80, 'defensa': 50, 'ataque_especial': 70, 'defensa_especial': 60, 'velocidad': 150}, {'nombre': 'Pikachu', 'vida': 20, 'ataque': 20, 'defensa': 20, 'ataque_especial': 20, 'defensa_especial': 20, 'velocidad': 20}]
for dic in construir_equipo_pokemon(6,lista):
  print(dic)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin el while que oblica a repetirse saldria:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya he entendido en que me he equivocado, lo he corregido lo único que me faltaría seria hacer una lista con los nombres de pokemons que cumplen las condiciones para ser añadidos y los puntos en total. Muchas gracias por la corrección.

Comment: Agradecería que publicaras los resultados como texto, no como imagenes. Mis cansados ojos no distinguen el contenido y el zoom no ayuda mucho.